# Should OP comments be added to question by non-OP?

Tags: discussion

I just reviewed a suggested edit and rejected it because it was essentially just pasting a comment into the question. It seemed to me that the person who suggested the edit is farming for easy rep points rather than trying to improve the question. A new user could obviously flood the review queues if he decided to just go through questions and add information from the comments section into the question. I tried in vain to find anything about this as far as Stack Exchange policy or precedent.

Should I have accepted this suggested edit?

This is the review in question:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/55721

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is: does the edit improve the question? At a glance, it seems so: it is clarifying the goal of OP.  This information was originally placed by the OP in a comment, which is not the right place for it. Readers should not have to look through the comments to see what the question really is. So, moving it to the proper place is an improvement.

> A new user could obviously flood the review queues

Does this happen in practice, or are we solving a hypothetical problem? There is a limit on how many edits one can suggest at a time: [at most 5 on graduated sites such as Blender](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202).

> I tried in vain to find anything about this as far as Stack Exchange policy

Here it is: [Warn new users to edit important information into the question upon their first attempt to comment on a question of theirs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273507/warn-new-users-to-edit-important-information-into-the-question-upon-their-first)

> When you see this happening you should: Edit the information into the question yourself. If you do it as a suggested edit, make sure your "Edit comment" makes it clear that you are incorporating information from the comments.

To summarize: yes, when OP places information in a comment that should be in their post, moving it to the post is appropriate.

Comment: That's fair...didn't know about the 5 max reviews. I'm perhaps a bit too wary about rep farming with suggested edits. By only knowing English one can get a reasonable number of reputation points (I believe 2000) without actually knowing anything about a given topic.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think we get any reputation from edits here at BSE, so no farming could occur anyway.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos The question is about suggested edits. Suggested edits earn 2 rep upon approval. Users with sufficient reputation to edit posts directly, like yourself, do not earn reputation from edits.

Comment: Hum, I see. I don't recall I ever getting any rep from edits here, so either I never suggested one while my rep was lower here or they never got approved. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos [You never suggested an edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/19307/duarte-farrajota-ramos?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)